# How to run two-way repeated within subject comparisons in R?

Tags: r

I have this following data (3x3 within-subject design):

```
subj phase cope mean
1    A     a    ...
1    A     b    ...
1    A     c    ...
1    B     a    ...
1    B     b    ...
1    B     c    ...
1    C     a    ...
1    C     b    ...
1    C     c    ...
2    A     a    ...
2    A     b    ...
2    A     c    ...
2    B     a    ...
2    B     b    ...
2    B     c    ...
2    C     a    ...
2    C     b    ...
2    C     c    ...
...
```

Both phase and cope are categorical and the DV (mean) is continuous.

How do I run a 3-by-3 (ABCxabc) within subject ANOVA/lme with this data and what should I do for the post-hoc test?

After searching on the web, I have found the following 3 potential options:

```
1. baselinemodel <- lme(m ~ 1, random = ~1 | subj/phase/cope, data = csv_temp, method = "ML")
copemodel <- lme(m ~ cope, random = ~1 | subj/phase/cope, data = csv_temp, method = "ML")
phasemodel <- lme(m ~ phase, random = ~1 | subj/phase/cope, data = csv_temp, method = "ML")
fullmodel <- lme(m ~ phase + cope, random = ~1 | subj/phase/cope, data = csv_temp, method = "ML")
interactionmodel <- lme(m ~ phase * cope, random = ~1 | subj/phase/cope, data = csv_temp, method = "ML")
anova(baselinemodel, copemodel, phasemodel, fullmodel, interactionmodel)

2. m.lme <- lme(m ~ cope * phase, data = csv_temp, random = ~1 | subj)

3. m.lme <- lme(m ~ cope * phase, random = list(subj = pdBlocked(list(~1, pdIdent(~ cope - 1), pdIdent(~ phase - 1)))), data = csv_temp)
anova(m.lme)
```

They produced different results. Which way is the correct way? And how do I followup with post-hoc tests (at this time, neither method yield significant interactions)?

Comment: This might get a better response on https://stats.stackexchange.com/